# Selecting specific field in array of objects returns undefined but logging whole returning whole array gives ok values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, api, spotify

I'm trying to get podcast data with `SpotifyAPI. I am fetching the data on my node.js server and sending it as a json to client. I receive a typed object and trying to push this object to an array as I want to have an array of 50 podcasts each of them being an object:

```
export interface Episode {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    date: string;
    img: string;
    url: string
};
```

I'm sending token (to whole function component) and ids of shows I want to fetch

```
 const fetchEpisodesData = async (ids: string[]) => {
    let arr: any[] = [];
    ids.forEach(async (id, index) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:8080/podcastEpisodes?access_token=${tokenCode}&id=${id}`
  )

  const dataResponse = await response.json();
  arr.push(dataResponse)
  // )
});
console.log(arr);
};
```

When I `console.log(arr)` it shows what I pretty much want and an array of objects but when I `console.log(arr[1])` it returns undefined.
Any ideas?
Here is my code of the fetchinng function

```
export const useFetch = (tokenCode: string) => {
  // console.log(tokenCode);
  let array: any[] = [];
  const [data, setData]: any = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const getData = async (id: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:8080/podcastEpisodes?access_token=${tokenCode}&id=${id}`
    );
    const dataResponse = await response.json();
    return dataResponse;
  };
  const fetchdata = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:8080/podcast?access_token=${tokenCode}`
    );
    const dataResponse = await response.json();
    // const item = dataResponse.results[0];
    const myData = Object.keys(dataResponse).map((key) => {
      return dataResponse[key];
    });
    // console.log(myData[0].show.id)
    const idData = myData.map((data) => {
      return data.show.id as string;
    });
    // console.log(idData, 'idData')
    return idData;
    // console.log(dataResponse);
  };
 const fetchEpisodesData = async (ids: string[]) => {
    let arr: any[] = [];
    ids.forEach(async (id, index) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:8080/podcastEpisodes?access_token=${tokenCode}&id=${id}`
  )

  const dataResponse = await response.json();
  arr.push(dataResponse)
  // )
});
console.log(arr);
};
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchdata().then((res) => {
      // console.log(res);
     fetchEpisodesData(res);
    });
  }, [tokenCode]);
  return { data, loading };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is a bit subtle.

You are pushing only *one* element, the `dataResponse` object, to your array `arr` here:

```js
arr.push(dataResponse)
```

Since you don't push any other value, and arrays in Javascript are 0-indexed, you will only find your value in `arr[0]`, but `arr[1]` will return `undefined`.

Now, **if** you wanted to fill your array `arr` with an array that would be getting in `dataResponse`, then you should [*spread*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array when doing `.push()`, so you'll be pushing all elements found in such `dataResponse` array object.

Like so:

```js
  const dataResponse = await response.json();

  // this works only **if** dataResponse is an array
  // and you want to add all elements to your 'arr' array
  arr.push(...dataResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you for replay but It still doesn't work. I think it may be because I need some Promise.all() for it to work but whatever I try it gives the same or even worst results. Do you have any ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: Please share the rest of the relevant/related code you have. Based on what you´ve showed so far, it should be working with this fix

Comment: I edited the post. Thank you for your answer.